# Wireless card listed but disabled

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, network-interface, yocto

I have a WNFQ-258ACN(BT) wireless network card installed in a PICO-KBU4 board. It is running Yocto Linux.

When I make ifconfig no wireless interface shows up.
When I list PCI devices it shows up **[disabled]**:

```
# lspci -vnn

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Device [1dac:0258]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at df000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
```

I have loaded the driver ath9k.

```
# lsmod
[...]
iwlwifi               241664  0
ath9k                  94208  0
ath9k_common           16384  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              421888  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
mac80211              544768  1 ath9k
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              499712  5 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,iwlwifi,mac80211
[...]
```

Why does it appear disabled? and how can I enable it?

EDIT:

```
root@aaeonc:~# rfkill list all
0: hci0: bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: You need the [ath10k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k) driver.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: rfkill list all

Comment: ath10k is not an option when I run menuconfig for Yocto. However I am using kernel 4.14.76 so I don't understand why it is not showing up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Freddy mentioned [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572348/wireless-card-listed-but-disabled/572355#comment1065132_572348), [ath9k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k/devices) does not support my device, so the solution is install [ath10k](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k) driver.